# Recommended delay for sendmail() for mass emails

Tags: php, email

I've made a script to send about 500 emails a go but the problem is my shared hosting has a max execution time for php scripts of about 45 seconds. I've tried overwriting this to no avail with `ini_set('max_execution_time', x);` and `set_time_limit(0)` but my host seems to override that.

To get around this I've made a javascript application which parses packets of contacts to the php script to process. I'm aiming for 5-10 contacts at a time.

I've been advised to have a delay of `sleep(rand(2,20));` after each `sendmail()`... but up to 20 seconds delay is too large considering my script's max execution time.

What is the minimum recommended time delay after sending each message considering I'd be sending up to about 500 emails in a given day?

Comment: how do you invoke that script? do you run it inside a browser or is it started by a cron job?

Comment: Alright, I guess you call the script within a browser, as you use javascript…

Comment: Yeah in the browser from my javascript application

Comment: You should calculate the delay of PHP Mail(). It's server setup by your host, to avoid spaming. Check the `max_execution_time` that you host has first

Comment: and there is prob some max amount that CAN be sent everyday since your host always try to limit those... it is best to move those into a emailing provider like maichamp or campaign monitor

Comment: Max execution time is 45 seconds, I know that. I might try sleep 1 to 8 seconds and parse 5 contacts at a time. That should work.

Comment: There's no one absolute answer. It depends on your server configuration and your hosting company limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest another scheme:

- Write a PHP script that just takes POST input from an HTML page you built. The script sends just **one** email to one recipient.
- Write an HTML file that just posts a form (recipient, subject, message,…) to that PHP script. The form submission should be done with AJAX. Add some JavaScript, that handles the random timeout for submissions and recipient management.

This approach splits your problem and you should not need to worry about PHP maximum execution time anymore. Your PHP access should be somehow [password protected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).